# What does this sentence mean? (complex-sentences)

Tags: meaning, phrases, complex-sentences

English is not my native language, so I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of this sentence, someone could explain its meaning in other words?

"You may not put it in your eye, but it meets the guidance"

Thank you!

Comment: What is that sentence talking about? What guidance? In order to explain something, as much information as possible is needed.

Comment: The source is here: http://www.lasikcomplications.com/fdatranscripts.htm . But even with that context, I'm having a hard time understanding what's intended.  My current best guess is "*You may not [want to] put it in [your own] eye, but it [nevertheless] meets the guidance [i.e. is a legally/medically compliant device]*". But that's just a guess. There's too much jargon and committee-ese / legal ass-covering in that transcript for me to do better than that.

Comment: Actually this direct link to the FDA transcript has more detail: http://www.fda.gov/ohrms/dockets/ac/03/transcripts/3991t1.htm .

Comment: Thanks you both Andrew and Dan,
Dan, your guess makes a lot of sense to me.
Thanks!